# Changing class break schemes in QGIS to eliminate overlap?

Tags: qgis, symbology

When using Graduated Symbology in QGIS, by default the bounds seem to be overlapping.  For example, class 1 shows 0-100.000; class 2 shows 100.000-200.000; class 3 shows 200.000-300.000 where it appears as though the value 100 is captured in class 1 & 2; 200 is captured in class 2 & 3.

Is there a way to change the default class breaks so they are not overlapping (e.g. Class 1 = 0-100; class 2 = 101-200; class 3 = 201-300)?

I know in ArcGIS you can adjust the number of decimal points in the label.

Answer (score 3):

Uncheck "Link class boundaries" under "Layer Properties" >> "Style"

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me (QGIS 2.8.1). Still creates overlapping classes.

Comment: Not working in 2.12.3 (Win 8.1) either, maybe this needs a bug report.

Comment: This is a different thing, the post is *not* answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem like there is a auto setting to account for this, but you can manually do it by clicking on the value itself to update the class bounds, see caption below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into this.  I have been manually changing the class bounds in the past but my concern is that values will be dropped.  For example, in the image you provided, data with values 56.5 - 57.0 are not captured. Even if I manually changed the classes so they juxtapose, how do I know if I should decrease the upper bound or increase the lower bound?  Again, using your example - should I change the upper bound of class 1 (change to 1.0-56.40 whereas class 2 stays 56.5-112.0) or change the lower bound of class 2 (class 1  stays 1.0-56.5 and class 2 changes to 56.6-112.0)?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is no way of doing this without manually adjusting the class breaks.

There are two open issues related to this:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29852

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/24882

It is *probably* just a text display error where the *actual* class breaks are not displayed but the all-inclusive breaks mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question, too, though for QGIS 3.28.

I *think* that this link [QGIS: Class boundaries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166585/qgis-class-boundaries) provides an answer to the original question.

Mods should feel free to alter the post so it conforms to the convention.