# QGIS: Class boundaries

Tags: qgis, vector, cartography, classification, qgis-2.8

I have seen that people already had issues about overlapping class boundaries with the classification of graduated vector data. 
I am wondering if there is somewhere written in the documentation if the upper class boundary contains the stated value or if the class ends "just before" the stated value (<). So if I want to adjust class boundaries in the legend do I write 0 -< 10, 10 - <20 ... or is it 0 - 10, >10 - 20, ... ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's in the documentation, but the canonical answer (determined through examination of the source) is:

- For the FIRST CLASS ONLY, it's value >= lower_range AND value <= upper_range
- For ALL OTHER CLASSES, it's value > lower_range and value <= upper_range

So the first class will also include the lower_range, but all other classes won't.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find it in the documentation but I think I have an answer:

When I change to rule-based style the boundaries are set according the boundaries I have defined before manually in the graduated style. Now in the rule-based boundaries the rules are automatically set to something like this:

`Bushenge_fpcoveragerate > 20.600000 AND Bushenge_fpcoveragerate <= 50.000000`

So I assume that also for the normal classification the upper class always contains the stated value while the next class starts "just above" this value.

Still I would be happy if someone could confirm and give me a hint where to find it (if it's written down somewhere) in the documentation.

Comment: Not quite - see my clarification below